# Image zoom in hover effect when there is an overlay on image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

There is an overlay over the image. Without the overlay, the image will have the hover zoom-in effect with the class zoom-effect-1 and effect-image-1. How do I do it so that the image will zoom in (when hovering) even when there is an overlay using CSS?

I am using Bootstrap 5.2

Thank you in advance.

```css
.trip-card {
  position: relative;
}

.trip-card img {
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.525);
}


/*zoom does not work when there is overlay*/

.zoom-effect-1 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.zoom-effect-1 img {
  border-radius: 30px;
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}

.zoom-effect-1:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
}

.effect-image-1 {
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.zoom-effect-1 img {
  transition: all .4s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s linear;
  -moz-transition: all .4s linear;
  -o-transition: all .4s linear;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="trip-card p-4 col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 ">
    <div class="effect-image-1 zoom-effect-1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" class="w-100" />
    </div>
    <div class="overlay text-white d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center m-4">
      <div>
        <h3 class="text-center">Trip Name</h3>
        <p>2 Oct 2022 - 22 Oct 2022</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - Please take the [tour] and read our [ask] page for tips on how to improve this question.  For starters, make sure you have a [mre] that reproduces the issue

Comment: can you add a tag with the version of bootstrap you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your HTML markup cause your current markup is overlapped the images see the correct code below your CSS is okay just need to update the HTML markup

```css
.trip-card {
  position: relative;
}

.trip-card img {
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.525);
}


/*zoom does not work when there is overlay*/

.zoom-effect-1 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.zoom-effect-1 img {
  border-radius: 30px;
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}

.zoom-effect-1:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
}

.effect-image-1 {
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.zoom-effect-1 img {
  transition: all .4s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s linear;
  -moz-transition: all .4s linear;
  -o-transition: all .4s linear;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="trip-card p-4 col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 ">
    <div class="effect-image-1 zoom-effect-1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" class="w-100" />
       <div class="overlay text-white d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center m-4">
      <div>
        <h3 class="text-center">Trip Name</h3>
        <p>2 Oct 2022 - 22 Oct 2022</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
   
  </div>
</body>
```